# What is the problem with this function

Tags: c++, binary-search-tree

hi
I was writing a BST and wrote following function for adding Child.

```
void addChild(T value)  
{  
  temp = root;  
  while(0 != temp)  
  {  
     temp1 = temp;  
     if(value  > temp->getValue())  
          temp = temp->getRightChild();   
      else  
           temp = temp->getLeftChild();  
  }  
  if(temp1->getValue() > value)  
  {   
       temp1->setRightChild(new Child(value));  
  }  
  else  
  {  
       temp1->setLeftChild(new Child(value));  
  }  
}
```

I am giving "23 12 122 1 121 15" as input. Root is node 23 which i am creating in constructor of class.

**Problem:** When i am doing tree traversal i am getting only 23 and 15 as output.
**Question** : What am i doing wrong in this function ?

Comment: perhaps there is a problem with your traversal function? Also, I don't see a declaration for `temp` and `temp1` variables. Are they global??

Anyway, I suggest using a debugger (e.g. `gdb`) to follow the code. It should be quite simple to find the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
if(value > temp1->getValue())
```

...otherwise your insertion condition differs from your search for a spot in the loop above.

Comment: Shouldn't he add a if(root == null) return; at the beginning of the function, as well ?

Comment: @Muggen - maybe `if(root == null) {root = new Child(value);return;}` - but he did mention that root was set in his constructor.

Answer (score 1):

The conditions are mixed up.

if(value > temp->getValue()) : getRight

is the opposite to

if(temp1->getValue() > value) : setRight

Try just changing the last condition.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with previous answers by Captain and sje, but they don't explain the severe, should we say, underpopulation of your tree. The possible problem is that you add **value** as a child of **temp1**, discarding previous child altogether. That is probably done in T::setRightChild() and T::setLeftChild() functions.

Comment: The incorrect condition does explain the results: if you search and find you should add a right child, but then add a new left child (possibly overwriting the pointer to a bunch of existing children) you'll lose data (and leak memory). If your point is that there ought to be some checking for this possibility, it's probably a good one.

Comment: Hard to say what happens outside. This function requires quite a few preconditions to work properly.